# Write File to disk chunk by chunk using web browser and client side javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser, fileapi

Is it possible with newest Chrome, Firefox or IE to ask the user for a Save As location for a file and then write the file chunk by chunk with your own javascript algorithm "appending" bytes to the desired/choosen by user location. Let me clarify:

1. Ask the user to point a Save As location for a filename ex: C:\ggg.png (but the data not saved yet)
2. After that be able to write data to it programatically chunk by chunk in some Blob or something?

Comment: Something like this? http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

Comment: Yes, like this. But when I reviewed the code somehow I expected to be more simple. It's real hell inside :) I currently have a fileWriter object created by fileEntry.createWriter() into which I write my chunks. What should I do to trigger a "file download" event before I start writing my chunks?